# How to traverse a tree between two keys

Tags: c, glib, b-tree

I want to traverse a tree using glib. But `g_tree_transverse()` has been deprecated, and `g_tree_foreach()` will use all elements and it will be inefficient.

How can I traverse the tree between two keys without going through all the elements, and without using the `g_tree_transverse()` or `g_tree_foreach()`?

Comment: Probably not the answer you want, but if you're having to do this, it suggests that a tree may not be the data structure you want to be using in the first place.

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49863758/how-can-i-search-effectively-in-a-btree-on-glib-without-use-foreach (but cannot be marked as such).